# Do one time triggered tasks scheduled to repeat periodically survive a reboot?

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

I had set up a task to trigger on boot, then repeat every 5 minutes.  To my disappointment, running the task did not start the "repeat" functionality.  Rather than reboot, I added another trigger to start it "one time", then repeat every 5 minutes.  My question is whether the repetition on the one-time task will cause it to restart after boot, giving me two repeating instances of the task after a reboot -- one from each trigger?  Or will the "one time" trigger be ignored on reboot, giving me what I desire -- a single, repeating task every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation, I found that a one-time task that is set up to repeat indefinitely on a scheduled does carry over a reboot.  The task will run at the next scheduled time in accordance with the settings on the scheduled task.  It isn't necessary to have a boot time trigger to restart the sequence of task repeats.